# getting ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows while calling a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE cmb_staging (
    e_id               NUMBER(10),
    e_name             VARCHAR2(30),
    e_loc              VARCHAR2(30),
    validation_status  VARCHAR2(30),
    validation_result  VARCHAR2(30)
);

insert into cmb_staging values(1,'A','AA',null,null);
insert into cmb_staging values(1,'B','BB',null,null);
insert into cmb_staging values(2,'C','CC',null,null);
insert into cmb_staging values(2,'D','DD',null,null);
insert into cmb_staging values(3,'A','AA',null,null);

CREATE TABLE cmb_target (
    e_id    NUMBER(10),
    e_name  VARCHAR2(30),
    e_loc   VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE cmb_reject (
    e_id               NUMBER(10),
    e_name             VARCHAR2(30),
    e_loc              VARCHAR2(30),
    validation_status  VARCHAR2(30),
    validation_result  VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_TAB
   (    TOT_RECORDS NUMBER(10,0), 
    SUCCESS_RECORDS NUMBER(10,0), 
    FAILED_RECORDS NUMBER(10,0), 
    PROCESS_STATUS VARCHAR2(30)
   );
```

Procedure :

```
create or replace procedure sp_dup_rec(ov_err_msg OUT varchar2)
    is
      lv_succ_rec number(30);
      lv_fail_rec number(30);
      lv_count number(30);
    begin
      lv_succ_rec := 0;
      lv_fail_rec := 0;

      UPDATE cmb_staging
      SET   validation_status = 'Fail',
            validation_result    = CASE
                                WHEN e_id IS NULL
                                THEN 'Id is not present'
                                ELSE 'Id is longer than expected'
                                END
      WHERE e_id is null
      OR    LENGTH(e_id) > 4;

--If there are duplicates id then it should go into cmb_reject table
select e_id into lv_count from cmb_staging;
if lv_count < 1 then
      MERGE INTO cmb_target t
        USING (SELECT e_id,
             e_name,
             e_loc
      FROM   cmb_staging
      WHERE  validation_status IS NULL) S
        ON (t.e_id = S.e_id)

            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
                t.e_name = s.e_name,
                t.e_loc = s.e_loc


            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (t.e_id,t.e_name,t.e_loc)
                VALUES (s.e_id,s.e_name,s.e_loc);

      lv_succ_rec := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
else
      insert into cmb_reject
      select s.*
      from   cmb_staging s
      WHERE  validation_status = 'Fail';

      lv_fail_rec := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
end if;

      dbms_output.put_line('Inserting into Summary table');
      insert into summary_tab(
        tot_records,
        success_records,
        failed_records
      ) values (
        lv_succ_rec + lv_fail_rec,
        lv_succ_rec,
        lv_fail_rec
      );

      COMMIT;
      ov_err_msg := 'Procedure completed succesfully';
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ov_err_msg := 'Procedure end up with errors'|| sqlerrm;
        ROLLBACK;
    END sp_dup_rec;
```

Calling a procedure :

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    v_err_msg varchar2(100);
begin
    sp_dup_rec(v_err_msg);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_err_msg);
end;
```

Hi Team,
I am getting ora-01422 error while calling a procedure. Basically, I want to insert duplicate records into the cmb_reject tab because the merge statement will fail and I will get ora - 30296 error if I will use only merge. SO, I have written if condition wherein it will fetch the count and if the count is more then will insert into cmb_reject tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
--If there are duplicates id then it should go into cmb_reject table
select e_id into lv_count from cmb_staging;
```

This raises the exception as you are trying to insert all 5 `e_id` values into a single variable and it raises a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception. (Apart from the fact that it is not identifying duplicates.)

---

Rather than trying to identify duplicates as a separate part of the process, you can do all the processing in the original `UPDATE` (in this case, converting it to a `MERGE` statement):

```sql
create or replace procedure sp_dup_rec(ov_err_msg OUT varchar2)
is
  lv_succ_rec number(30);
  lv_fail_rec number(30);
  lv_count number(30);
begin
  MERGE INTO cmb_staging dst
  USING (
    SELECT ROWID AS rid,
           CASE
           WHEN e_id IS NULL
           THEN 'Id is not present'
           WHEN LENGTH(e_id) > 4
           THEN 'Id is longer than expected'
           WHEN num_e_id > 1
           THEN 'Duplicate IDs'
           END AS failure_reason
    FROM   (
      SELECT e_id,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e_id) AS num_e_id
      FROM   cmb_staging
    )
    WHERE  e_id IS NULL
    OR     LENGTH(e_id) > 4
    OR     num_e_id > 1
  ) src
  ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET validation_status = 'Fail',
        validation_result = failure_reason;

  MERGE INTO cmb_target t
  USING (
    SELECT e_id,
           e_name,
           e_loc
    FROM   cmb_staging
    WHERE  validation_status IS NULL
  ) S
  ON (t.e_id = S.e_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET t.e_name = s.e_name,
        t.e_loc = s.e_loc
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (t.e_id,t.e_name,t.e_loc)
    VALUES (s.e_id,s.e_name,s.e_loc);

  lv_succ_rec := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

  insert into cmb_reject
  select s.*
  from   cmb_staging s
  WHERE  validation_status = 'Fail';

  lv_fail_rec := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

  dbms_output.put_line('Inserting into Summary table');
  insert into summary_tab(
    tot_records,
    success_records,
    failed_records
  ) values (
    lv_succ_rec + lv_fail_rec,
    lv_succ_rec,
    lv_fail_rec
  );

  COMMIT;
  ov_err_msg := 'Procedure completed succesfully';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ov_err_msg := 'Procedure end up with errors'|| sqlerrm;
    ROLLBACK;
END sp_dup_rec;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60bb3daac25af2e8c9bcbde84d808b81)*

Comment: Could you please explain in short why we have rowid and how it will get matched with dst row id?

Comment: @Vicky [`ROWID` is a pseudo-column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-F6E0FBD2-983C-495D-9856-5E113A17FAF1) that is effectively a pointer to the exact location of the row in the database file and allows the queries to be correlated without having to search through the table twice (as you may have to do if you correlated on a unique key).

Answer (score 1):

The error stack should tell you the line that is throwing the error.  My guess is that the line is

```
select e_id 
  into lv_count 
  from cmb_staging;
```

because that query doesn't make sense.  If there are multiple rows in `cmb_staging`, the query will throw the ORA-01422 error because you can't put multiple rows in a scalar variable.  It seems highly probable that you'd at least want your query to do a `count`.  And most likely with some sort of predicate.  Something like

```
select count(*)
  into lv_count 
  from cmb_staging;
```

would avoid the error.  But that likely doesn't make sense given your comments where you say "it should go into the cmb_reject table" which implies that there is a singular object.  This change would cause `lv_count > 0` whenever there were any rows in `cmb_staging` and it seems unlikely that you want to always reject rows.

My rough guess is that you really mean "two rows with the same e_id" when you say "duplicate".  If that's right

```
select e_id, count(*)
  from cmb_staging
 group by e_id
having count(*) > 1
```

will show you the duplicate `e_id` values.  You could then

```
  insert into cmb_reject
  select s.*
  from   cmb_staging s
  where  e_id in (select s2.e_id
                    from cmb_staging s2
                   group by s2.e_id
                  having count(*) > 1);
```

If you don't really care about performance (I'm assuming based on the questions you've asked that you're just learning PL/SQL and you're not trying to manage a multi-TB data warehouse load) and just want to process the records in a loop

```
for stg in (select s.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by s.e_id) cnt
              from cmb_staging s)
loop
  if( stg.cnt > 1 )
  then
    insert into cmb_reject( e_id, e_name, e_loc )
      values( stg.e_id, stg.e_name, stg.e_loc );
    l_fail_cnt := l_fail_cnt + 1;
  else 
    merge into cmb_target tgt
      using( select stg.e_id e_id,
                    stg.e_name e_name,
                    stg.e_loc e_loc
               from dual ) src
         on( src.e_id = tgt.e_id )
       when not matched 
       then 
         insert( e_id, e_name, e_loc )
           values( src.e_id, src.e_name, src.e_loc )
       when matched
       then
         update set e_name = src.e_name,
                    e_loc  = src.e_loc;
      
    l_success_cnt := l_success_cnt + 1;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am learning PL/SQL. Could you please suggest which approach to follow if we care for performance as well? For loop or direct query? If direct query then while calling a procedure it will throw ora 30296 error because of the merge statement. Please advise

Comment: @Vicky - It is (essentially) always faster to use pure SQL if you can use pure SQL.  This difference isn't going to be meaningful for hundreds of rows but is very important when you're loading millions of rows.  I see no reason that the `merge` statement I posted would throw an error because the dupes are already filtered out.  MT0's answer (which I upvoted) will undoubtedly be more efficient than row-by-row processing for very large data sets.  But row-by-row processing is generally much easier for students to learn and understand and extend.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, would like to ask you if I want to gain more knowledge in PL/SQL then is there anything available that I can work upon to sharp my knowledge. By something I mean to say like any online coding/books/any channel?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
--If there are duplicates id then it should go into cmb_reject table
select e_id into lv_count from cmb_staging;
```

As there's no `WHERE` clause which would restrict number of rows being returned, if `cmb_staging` contains 2 (or more) rows, query will fail because you can't put that many rows into a scalar `lv_count` variable.

Looks like you actually meant to say

```
select count(*) into lv_count from cmb_staging;
```

as the next line says

```
if lv_count < 1 then
```

Comment: Basically I want to check if duplicate e_id's are present then it should insert into cmb_reject else it should insert into cmb_target. Count(*) will check a whole number of records that are not required. Any suggestions?

Comment: As I said - include WHERE clause which will restrict counting to IDs you're interested in.